# Capybara can't find user for delete action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara

I'm using RSpec (v. 3.1.0) and Capybara (v. 2.4.3) to test my Rails 4 application.  My user delete spec.rb contains the following code:

```
it "is successful when clicking the destroy link" do
      visit "/users"          
      save_and_open_page
within "#user_#{user.id}" do                        
    click_link "Destroy"            
end

    expect(page).to have_content("User was successfully destroyed.")
```

Capybara throws the following error:

```
 1) Deleting User is successful when clicking the destroy link
 Failure/Error: within "#user_#{user.id}" do
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find css "#user_509"
```

Save_and_open_page shows FactoryGirl created a user for the test.  The error message indicates the user's id is 509. My program's code (delete method) works as expected, so the problem appears to be my test code. What can I do to help Capybara find the user?  Thanks for any help!

UPDATE:  Here's the HTML source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
  <head>    
  <title>Users | App </title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/appointments.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/cardio_exercises.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/members.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/sessions.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/strength_exercises.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/trainers.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/users.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/appointments.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/cardio_exercises.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/members.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/sessions.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/static_pages.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/strength_exercises.js?body=1"></script>
```

</script>

Home

[Help](/help)

[Log in](/login)

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Listing Users</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th>User Name</th>      
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Member</th> 
  <th>Trainer</th>     
  <th colspan="3"></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>ColeCole</td>        
    <td>xx@xxx.com</td>
    <td>true</td>
    <td>false</td>      
    <td><a href="/users/14">Show</a></td>
    <td><a href="/users/14/edit">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/users/14" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<br>

 <a href="/users/new">New User</a>

  <footer class="footer">
 <small>
 The <a href="https://xxxx.herokuapp.com/">xxxx</a>
  by <a href="https://xxxx.herokuapp.com/">xxxx</a>
 </small>
 <nav>
<ul>
  <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://xxxx.herokuapp.com/#">xxxx</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</footer>
  <pre class="debug_dump">--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
action: index
controller: users
</pre>
</div>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the page launchy opens to see if there is a CSS selector with id="user_509"?

Comment: Launchy shows user_509: <td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/users/509" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a></td>

Comment: Can you just do "click_link "Destroy""  and remove the CSS selection?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean. I commented out within "#user_#{user.id}" do, but got error:  undefined local variable or method `page' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::DeletingUser:Class (NameError)
.  Please clarify what you're suggesting I do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work if you only have one delete button on the page:

```
it "is successful when clicking the destroy link" do
  visit "/users"                                
  click_link "Destroy"           
expect(page).to have_content("User was successfully destroyed.")
```

Edit: I'm going to assume you are not very familiar with CSS selectors. With Capybara, when you say:

```
#user_#{user.id}
```

You are not grabbing text such as "user_509" but rather you are grabbing a DOM element with the identity of "user_509." Thus to have Capybara find that element in your code, you would have to have something like this:

```
<a id="user_509" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/users/14" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
```

Merely having a text field would not suffice as text is not part of the DOM.

Comment: It works; there is only one delete action on the page. I still don't know why Capybara couldn't find the user by id.

Comment: If you update your answer with a little more of the HTML around the Destroy link, I could probably tell you :)

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if that clarifies things for you.

Comment: That's odd ... Capybara has no problems finding other objects by id in my application using similar code as "within "#user_#{user.id}" For example:  I am able to use visit "/members"  "within "#member_#{member.id}" to have Capybara find a member by id.

Comment: Capybara is not finding Ruby objects when it uses something like "#member_#{member.id}." Instead it is finding a CSS selector that is part of the DOM, so somewhere in your HTML for members there must be some CSS selector being automagically generated with the correct ID. It has to be a CSS selector. That is just how Capybara works. I suggest you do some tutorials on CSS or jQuery to better understand the DOM. Hopefully that doesn't come across as too blunt! Learning how the DOM works is not hard, but will be well worth your time :)

Comment: Discovered the problem:  I forgot to set the dom_id in the user view!  The test passes when I place <tr id="<%= dom_id(user) %>"> in the user index view.  Launchy confirms a successful deletion. Your point about "grabbing a DOM element" caused me to ask myself if I had set the dom_id. That was the problem.   I'll check this post solved ... thanks!